# How to Get Individual Row for Each Submitted URL?

Tags: sqlite, flask

I have a HTML input box that I want to be able to submit URLs into. Only problem is that when I go to submit multiple urls, they are inserted into 1 row in the SQLite database in one big blob. 
    "http://google.com/http://stack.com/http://aol.com/"

```
When I want them to be:
Row 1: http://google.com/
Row 2: http://stack.com/
Row 3: http://aol.com/
```

Essentially, for every URL in the input box to be put into it's own individual row.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure I see a problem here.  What is stopping you from splitting the content on the server side into separate URLs?

Comment: Well, anyway for me to split the URLs I'll go with. Any tips on how I can achieve that? I looked into triggers but I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two steps.

1. Split the URL(consider it as a string) on the basis of a token ('/').
2. Then loop over the split string (as per example 3) and save it in DB.
   Here is the example code.

   ```
      var str = 'http://google.com/http://stack.com/http://aol.com/';
      var str_array = str.split('/');
   ```